# Disabling "OK" telnet confirmation

Tags: linux, cmd, server, connection, telnet

When testing connection via telnet, the console displays confirmation in the form of "**OK**":

```
[root@admin wojtek]# telnet admin.adm.local 12345
Trying 223.58.1.10...
Connected to admin.adm.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
test
OK
```

If you use a similar solution continuously, the message "OK" will fill up the buffer (**squid**), which will reduce performance.

Question: how to delete the "OK" message?

Telnet is tested on the linux server, so any configuration is carried out by the console.
Btw the address and other data are correct, the above data is an example.

Comment: Why do you use telnet to test a connection. A simple `nc -vz <ip> <port>` does the job better

Comment: @mbieren thank you for your answer. Port scanning works only on several ports (nc -z host.example.com 20-30). In my case it does not work, because I have one port:
`nc: invalid option -- 'z'
Ncat: Try --help or man(1) ncat for more information, usage options and help. QUITTING.`

Comment: What distribution are you using eg. on Centos 7 this nmap-ncat does not support this option

Comment: I am sending logs from proxy to Hadoop (Hortonworks Apache Hadoop). Every time the logs are sent, the console confirms "OK" which I would like to delete.

Comment: ?? But OK means in that case ... OK go on send me the data or ... data received .. I dont see any overhead here

Comment: You're right, but the telnet test content is sent to squid. Squid does not expect any answers and they do not read them, so when the buffers are full
communication will stop.